# Encrypting text file with AES-256 CBC

Tags: c++, security, encryption, aes

I've been trying to pick up C++ and computer security in my own free time and I've been attempting some CTF challenges.

The challenge was about finding out the number of words (N) in a text file (x.txt), and using N as a key to encrypt the text file (x.txt) using AES-256 CBC and outputting a new text file (y.txt) with the encrypted contents.

I have no problems getting the number of words from the text file, but I was just wondering if anyone knows how to perform the encryption stated?

I've been reading up on OpenSSL for this but I can't proceed further. I assume the IV would be zero in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I've been reading up on OpenSSL for this but I can't proceed further"* - People will probably need more detail about what exactly you are having problems with.

Comment: Most of the information I found was regarding command line encryption but I haven't found any tutorials on how to implement it in a C++ program.

Answer (score 2):

> *I assume the IV would be zero in this case?*

An IV or [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector), is the "seed" for encryption. It is needed so that plaintexts that are similar don't look similar when encrypted. It is meant to never repeat between different encryption runs and is not secret. A zero IV (or any other fixed IV) would thus defeat the purpose.

A typical approach with AES-CBC is during *encryption* to generate a random IV and store it together with the ciphertext. Then during *decryption* read it in and use it to initialize the decryptor.

To know more about the OpenSSL API's to use, refer to [OpenSSL Wiki - Symmetric Encryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: Typically, the IV is prepended to the ciphertext. Since the IV size is fixed, it is easy to extract from the beginning without any delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning about AES too. Here are some resources I found useful:

> How to perform AES encryption:

It boils down to 4 steps per round:

1. Substitute bytes (using the S-box)
2. Shifting the rows
3. Mixing the columns
4. Adding the round key

There's a really good video about how to perform each AES round by Professor Paar. [Here is a link to his AES video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHuibtoL_qk). His whole channel is really a gold mine with regards to learning crypto. Note: You will need to hard code the S-box or include it somehow.

One thing Prof. Paar doesn't explain in the video is key expansion (aka how to get each round key). You can find a java implementation of key expansion [on Professor Wagner's page here.](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/AESkeys.html) It should be relatively straight forward to refactor into C++. Just remember to include the round constant table.